# How do I return an array from an external function in Node

Tags: arrays, node.js, module.exports

I have a file which contains the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var loadSingleCsv = function (filename) {
  fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {

      var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);

      dataArray.forEach((element,index, dataArray) => {
        dataArray[index]= element.split(",");
      });
      dataArray.forEach((element,index, dataArray) => {
        dataArray[index] = `${element[0]}, ${element[1]}, ${element[2]}, ${element[3]}, ${element[4]}`;
      });

      console.log(dataArray);  // this prints to the console as expected

    return dataArray;
    });
  }  

module.exports = { loadSingleCsv };
```

When I call it from another file, the array shows as 'undefined'. Here is my code:

```
const loadCsv = require ('../../load-csv-file');

dataArray = loadCsv.loadSingleCsv('./csv-files/rcm-data-01.csv');

console.log(dataArray);
```

I'm assuming that this is a real newbie error, but I would appreciate any help you can give.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with loading the file

```
const loadCsv = require ('../../load-csv-file');

dataArray = loadCsv.loadSingleCsv('./csv-files/rcm-data-01.csv');
```

Please check the file path.

Comment: make the file path like this"folder/subfolder/filename" not like this"'../../load-csv-file'"